# Getting black stripes when cropping image with Intervention crop()

Tags: php, image, laravel, crop, intervention

I'm using [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/) (php, laravel) to crop an image to user-defined dimensions at user-defined position:

```
$Image->crop($cropW, $cropH, $imgX1, $imgY1);
```

The problem is, that I'm getting some black stripes at the bottom of cropped images:

[image: Image: Under uploaded image you can see a black stripe]

I checked that before the crop function, the image is OK, so I'm sure, that it is the crop function, that makes the stripes. How can I get rid of those? Or is it possible to define a background color for the crop function?

Comment: It is possible that `$cropH` is greater than the original height so that it will be filled up with black colour?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not just a HTML/CSS issue? Because the screenshot you posted is from the UI, and the grey band might come from that. When you open the image on its own does it have the band?

Comment: Thank's for comments, but:

@mapek No it's not.

Comment: @Bogdan I'm sure it's not. When I open the file, I see the same :(

Comment: Could you please post the entire code that is responsible for the cropping, that includes the way you get/compute the 4 variables passed to the crop method.

Comment: @Bogdan Thank you for all your effort, but the black stripes disappeared and I can not generate them again... If the problem comes back, I'll come back to this question... Thank you again!

Comment: Any one have  solution for this problem  ?